# Rhythmbox not saving the album art permanently

Tags: rhythmbox

I run ubuntu 10.10 and use rhythmbox **(version 0.13.1)** regularly with the **albumartsearch** plugin installed. However when I change the album art it is only temporary. On moving to the next song it automatically removes the previous song's album art cover. (I do know about banshee but would like to use rhythmbox).

The cover art plugin is also installed by default however it cannot display some of the album covers since the songs are in my local language (tamil) hence it cannot retrieve the album cover from the internet. However the albumartsearch plugin seems to do the job although only temporarily.

Any reason why it might be?

I have tried looking for other rhythmbox plugins which might be similar to albumartsearch but in vain. Any help would be appreciated.

I have filed a bug in the albumartsearch plugin's website. Waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the Plugin isn't working at all because the Site where the Covers can be found has decided to disable Rhythmbox-Users completly because of too high traffic.

What you can do is searching your Covers manually via images.google.com, save them as folder.jpg in the album-folders and (if you want) inject the Artwork into your .mp3-files with a Tag-Editor like Mp3Tag (works fine with Wine).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to save the album art and navigate to it from rhythm box , tag it , and leave the folder there as is...MAYBE place a  dot (.) in front of it as to have it hidden until ctrl+h is hit. I use Songbird... (an old .deb before they quit on us Linux folks...) Just Google it :)

Comment: I used to use songbird before as well, however uninstalled it after they stopped supporting linux.