# Unable to add album art in Rhythmbox

Tags: 16.04, rhythmbox

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. In the Rhythmbox whenever I add an album-art to any song it doesn't saves it, when I change the song it suddenly disappears. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rhythmbox not saving the album art permanently](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18821/rhythmbox-not-saving-the-album-art-permanently)